# Show that holomorphic functions are infinitely differentiable without complex analysis

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an integration free proof (or heuristic) that once differentiable implies twice differentiable for complex functions?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63205/is-there-an-integration-free-proof-or-heuristic-that-once-differentiable-implie)

Is there a way to show that holomorphic functions, thought as real functions, are   $C^\infty$ , without using any Complex Analysis?

That is,

Let $f:A\rightarrow R^2$ where $A \subseteq R^2$ is open, f is differentiable on A, and satisfies the Cauchy Riemann Equations. Show that f is $C^\infty$ on $A$, without using any Complex Analysis definiton, theorem, or tool.

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula is basically Green's Theorem and that's where it starts.  So in a sense, the proof is very much not a complex analysis proof. 

Comment: Your question lacks motivation. Why are you interested in doing complex analysis without doing complex analysis?

Comment: I'm taking an undergrad complex analysis class, and I felt that this result (that holomorphic functions are infinitely differentiable) was surprising. I was curious whether it could be proved without complex variable theory.

Comment: As the answers below, there are ways to do this without complex analysis, but they are not easier to learn. The usual proof, using the Cauchy integral formula, is both miraculous and elegant. I suggest you try to live with that for now.

Comment: @Benoit: can't someone just be curious?  

Comment: It's a good question, but maybe more for math.stackexchange.com than here? It's not really a research level question.

Comment: But if you show that holomorphic functions are infinitely differentiable, doesn't that constitute complex analysis regardless of the method?  I'm inclined to construe the question as meaning without power series.

Answer (score 6):

It can be instructive to consider the Cauchy-Riemann equations as an elliptic system of partial differential equations. For elliptic systems, there is a $C^\infty$-regularity result similar to the one known for a single equation (see L. H\"ormander, Linear partial differential operators, Springer, 1963).

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Avoided by $C^2$ by using integrals.

Edit 2: I believe that the following manipulations of $U,V$ work out right...

If $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, then write $f(x,y) = (u(x,y), v(x,y))$. Now, let $U,V$ be the antiderivatives of $u,v$ with respect to $x$. Since $u,v \in C^1$, we claim that $U,V \in C^2$ and are harmonic. Using uniform convergence to exchange integral and derivative,

\begin{equation}
U_{xx} = D_x^2 \int u \ dx = D_x \int u_x \ dx = u_x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
U_{yy} = D_y^2 \int u \ dx = D_y \int u_y \ dx = D_y \int -v_x \ dx = -v_y = -u_x
\end{equation}

The computations for $V$ should be similar. Hence $U,V$ are harmonic.

A harmonic function is defined by satisfying the Laplace equation. We can prove that every real harmonic function is smooth by showing that the convolution of any harmonic function by a mollifier is in fact equal to the same harmonic function; this proves that the harmonic function is smooth. If you want a reference, see, for example, L. Craig Evans' textbook "Partial Differential Equations".

Comment: But to get that the real and imaginary parts are harmonic you need them to be $C^2$, and that wasn't assumed.

Comment: One could always use the Dirac operator.

Comment: Or just use "weakly harmonic". Proof given by Christopher Wong still works as is.

Comment: Yeah, using weak notions works. I've amended my solution to make that idea more concrete (since the OP said he's an undergrad).

Comment: But what do you mean by the antiderivative of a function of two variables?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. Let me edit this again...

Comment: No. Sorry but that doesn't work. If you integrate a $C^1$ function only in the $x$ variable, the result is not necessarily $C^2$, because you can't necessarily differentiate twice in the $y$ variable. You really need to define the notion of a weak derivative and define "weakly harmonic" in terms of weak derivatives.

Comment: If u,v are just differentiable (we don't assume they are $C^1$) does this approach still work? 

Comment: Maybe I'm tired. If $U$ is the antiderivative of $u$ with respect to $x$, is not true that $U_{yy} = D_y \int u_y \, dx = D_y \int -v_x \, dx = - v_y$? 

Comment: Ah, maybe you're right about that. But maybe you should put the details in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

This already got asked, and I answered it: [Is there an integration free proof (or heuristic) that once differentiable implies twice differentiable for complex functions?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63205/is-there-an-integration-free-proof-or-heuristic-that-once-differentiable-implie/63408#63408)

Comment: You are right! I'm sorry. Should I ask the question to be closed as duplicate?
